# What does the divided income number signify?

Tags: mutual-funds, dividends, starting-out-investing

[This mutual fund](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-investor/funds-and-etfs/funds/summary/?id=53617) has a distribution at the end of every month.

[image]

For example, the income dividend for October 2014 was 0.0301. Assuming I hold `$x` worth of units in this fund, what would my distribution have been for October 2014?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the unit for that column is "dollars per share". Since the reinvestment price is $11.49, you would have owned $x/$11.49 shares. Multiplying that out, your monthly dividend income for October would be (rounded off) $x*0.00262 -- or about 0.26 cents per $100 invested.

Of course if you're having them reinvest the dividend, this compounds over successive months. If everything remained constant, 1.00262 to the 12th power would be 1.031. Of course nothing remains constant.